# How to shorten a day in Full calendar selection?

Tags: fullcalendar

How to shorten a day in Full calendar selection?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "shorten" exactly, or how it relates to the screenshot? Also the modal dialog you're showing in the screenshot is not part of fullCalendar. Are you asking how to show the date without the time, perhaps? Or maybe the time without the seconds? Or something else entirely? You need to add more detail and a proper example of what you're expecting. As it stands your question is unclear and not answerable. Please provide an update, if you still need help. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Good afternoon @Adyson!!

When I select the dates in the fulcalendar it returns the end of the later day, I want it to capture exactly the dates I select.

`   select: function(info) {

        $('#cadastrar #startDate').val(info.startStr);
        $('#cadastrar #endDate').val(info.endStr);
        $('#cadastrar').modal('show');

        },`

Comment: Ok. Well I can't see fully what code you've written, so until you share that, no-one can help you. We cannot fix your code if you do not show it all. Please edit your question to include the description of the problem (from your comment) and the code you've used which is causing this problem. The "edit" button is just under your question near the blue "fullcalendar" tag. Please also see [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your problem, for more guidance. Do not post code into the comments where it is hard to read and unformatted. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Please remember that, as per the fullCalendar documentation, end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive**. So if, in the month view, you selected 7th, 8th and 9th, then due to the rule that end dates are exclusive, it's logical that the end date is the 10th because that's the first date which is immediately after the selected area.

Comment: Exactly!! And how do I change it @Adyson ?

Comment: Subtract one day from the date before you pass it to your modal, if that's what you want. But bear in mind that if you then use that to create an event in fullcalendar, it'll show up one day shorter than you intended (because, again, when you send an event to fullCalendar, it treats the end date as exclusive).